# Facebook Bug decoder- image meta data is getting a "was not a valid URL." error

Tags: html, metadata

Image meta data is getting a "was not a valid URL." error

**Here is the code**:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Separation Club">
<meta property="og:description" content="Your separation journey begins here.">
<!-- <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1.jpg"> -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://theseparationclub.com">
<meta property="og:image:url" content="{% static 'https://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1-crop.jpg' %}"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{% static 'https://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1-crop.jpg' %}"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600"/>
```

The url will open the image in a browser so it is valid. Any idea why this might not be working?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: make sure that `{% static 'https://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1-crop.jpg' %}` compiles to `https://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1-crop.jpg`

Comment: @OrAssayag I'm not sure how to compile that. I ripped the code from someone who was having my previous issue. When I didn't have the static brackets it said: "
Provided og:image URL, https://www.theseparationclub.com/images/elisabeth-option1-crop.jpg could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type."

Comment: @Alex here's an example of the output I am getting: https://imgur.com/cAGgPtl You'll see that the image will not load from the meta data.